# How set height row in excel with NPOI?

Tags: c#, npoi

How set height row in c# with NPOI?

To specify the width of the columns I'm using XSSFSheet.SetColumnWidth, but what does the command for the height of the cells look like?

Answer (score 7):

try  below approach

```
var row = sheet.CreateRow(0);
row.Height = 10 ;    
//Or     
sheet.GetRow(1).Height = 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

The height of the row is the same: 
XSSFSheet.GetRow(index).Heigh {get;set;}

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @kumar answer, you can set it like this

```
row.HeightInPoints = 16.5F;
```